# Is there a API to know if a particular service allows binding?

Tags: android, android-service

I am working on a app which tries to bind with a service, but it fails to do so because service it is trying bind is not exported for other apps to bind. This made me think if there is a way to know before hand if a specified service class accepts binding or not programmatically.

I know by checking  element of AndroidManifest.xml will suggest if exported = false or true. But I want to know the same by a API call or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, [`ServiceRecord`](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/ServiceRecord.java&exact_package=android&q=Service%20exported&type=cs) contains this exported' information, which Android has provided no way of getting access to.

Your best bet is to check for a `SecurityException` when you try to bind to the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but should really just assum you're not allowed to bind to a service unless the apps API explicitly exposes it.

Comment: It make sense, because if you know the service class already, you may as well be knowing if it encourages binding :).